# How to destructure an object with a key containing a hyphen into a variable?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

How do I destructure a property from an object where the key contains a hyphen?

Eg:

```
{
  accept-ranges:"bytes",
  cache-control:"public, max-age=0",
  content-length:"1174",
  content-type:"application/json",
  date:"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:45:03 GMT",
  etag:"W/"496-157892e555b"",
  last-modified:"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:14:57 GMT",
  x-powered-by:"Express"
}
```

Now to get the `content-type` and `x-powered-by` values from the object using destructuring?

Comment: I'm confused, you say you need from an array - yet you supplied an object. Which is it? An array of objects etc..?

Comment: Sorry my bad, typo.

Comment: A common typo! The keys are, like, right next to each other ^_^

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Just like you cannot declare a variable with a hyphen, you can't destructure directly to one. You will need to rename your variable to something else in order to access it on the current scope. You can use the following destructuring syntax to do that:

```js
const x = {
  "accept-ranges":"bytes",
  "cache-control":"public, max-age=0",
  "content-length":"1174",
  "content-type":"application/json",
  date:"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:45:03 GMT",
  etag:"W/496-157892e555b",
  "last-modified":"Mon, 03 Oct 2016 06:14:57 GMT",
  "x-powered-by":"Express"
};
const { "accept-ranges": acceptRanges } = x;
console.log(acceptRanges); // "bytes"
```